# JS/JestJS: How to test for a async mocked function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

As you can see in my testfile I've mocked all mongoDB methods.

Now I need to test, if `Content.update()` has been called. In this example code I'm testing for a called `console.log` which is working, but not want I want.
I don't understand why I can't test for `update()`

**/category.test.js**

```
import { updateCategory } from './category'
import DB from './lib/db'

test('should update document', async () => {
  DB.getDB = jest.fn(
    () => ({
      get: jest.fn(
        () => ({
          findOne: jest.fn(() => ({ some: 'content' })),
          update: jest.fn()
        })
      )
    })
  )
  console.log = jest.fn()

  return updateCategory({}, {
    id: '12345678901234567'
  }).then(() => {
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled()
    // instead check if `Content.update()` has been called
    expect(DB.getDB().get().update).toHaveBeenCalled() // throws `Expected mock function to have been called.`
  })
})
```

**/category.js**

```
import DB from './lib/db'

export async function updateCategory (obj, { id }) {
  const db = DB.getDB()
  const Content = db.get('content')
  const doc = await Content.findOne({ _id: id })

  console.log('ok');

  await Content.update(
    { _id: id },
    { $set: { category: 'new category' } }
  )
}
```

Comment: In the test there's no `Content`, that only exists in your `updateCategory` function. You'd need to check the mock you're passing in.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't understand how to test for the mock. I tried to use `expect(DB.getDB().get().update).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Comment: @user3142695 Have you tried using the proper [API](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) for mocking?

Comment: @OrB I think I tried that with my attempt. What is wrong with that?

Comment: @user3142695 Ah sorry, I get it now. `DB.getDB()` returns a new instance with every call, so the one used in `category.js` is not the one in the assertion. In any case, I find `jest.mock()` or [manual mocks](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html) more straightforward.

Comment: @OrB I really don't get it with `jest.mock()`. Could you please post an example.

Comment: See my answer to your other question. You're making testing hard on yourself with the design of your functions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48379986/37168

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the mock you want to spy on in a variable so you can track it:

```
import { updateCategory } from './category'
import DB from './lib/db'
jest.mock('./lib/db');

const mockUpdate = jest.fn();

test('should update document', async () => {
  DB.getDB.mockImplementation( // <-- available when you call jest.mock above, seems safer than overwriting the implementation in the real import
    () => ({
      get: jest.fn(
        () => ({
          findOne: jest.fn(() => ({ some: 'content' })),
          update: mockUpdate
        })
      )
    })
  )
  console.log = jest.fn()

  return updateCategory({}, {
    id: '12345678901234567'
  }).then(() => {
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled()
    // instead check if `Content.update()` has been called
    expect(mockUpdate).toHaveBeenCalled() // should work now
  })
})
```